# post id from view to controller through the url in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to find a user in my Spring-Boot application by its ID.
The Controller-method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "finduser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User get(@PathVariable Long id) throws NotFoundException {
    log.info("Invoked method: get with ID: " + id);
    log.warn("Searching for user with ID " + id);
    User findOne = userRepository.findOne(id);
    if (findOne == null){
        log.error("Unexpected error, User with ID " + id + " not found");
        throw new NotFoundException("User with ID " + id + " not found");
    }
    log.info("User found. Sending request back. ID of user is " + id);
    return findOne;
}
```

The body of my **finduser.html** is:

```
<body>

<h1>Find User:</h1>
<form th:object="${user}" th:action="@{finduser}"  method="post">
    <p>Find by ID: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

</body>
```

What should i change to pass the id from the view to my controller, so my controller can use the id and search for a user?

I think the id must be passed through the url because of

**@RequestMapping(value = "finduser/{id}"...)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the form `action` ([doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)):

> You can also include parameters in the form of path variables
>   similarly to normal parameters but specifying a placeholder inside
>   your URL’s path:
>
> `<a th:href="@{/order/{id}/details(id=3,action='show_all')}">`

in your case you can do like this for example:

`<form th:action="@{/finduser/{id}(id=${user.id})}">`

or if you prefer having the url in a variable:

`<form th:action="@{{finduser}/{id}(finduser=${finduser},id=${user.id})}">`